# I want to know how to create something like this alert for iphone app

Tags: ios

how could I create this menu for my iphone app?

[image]

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIActionSheet.  Look up the documentation